# debounce react-jsonschema-form validate function

Tags: reactjs, lodash, react-hooks, react-jsonschema-forms

I have a functional component that's using `react-jsonschema-form`, and I need to debounce the function that it runs to validate itself. The component looks something like this:

```js
const Form = props => {
  const validate = (formData, errors) => {
    // run some code to validate the form
    return errors
  }

  return (
    <SchemaForm
      validate={(formData, errors) => validate(formData, errors)}
    />
  )
```

I've tried to do the following approaches:

1. wrapping the validate function in debounce:

```js
const debouncedValidate = (formData, errors) => debounce(validate(formData, errors), 300);

return (
  <SchemaForm
    validate={(formData, errors) => validate(formData, errors)}
  />
)
```

2. ...tried useRef:

```js
const debouncedValidate = useRef(debounce((formData, errors) => validate(formData, errors), 300);

return (
  <SchemaForm
    validate={(formData, errors) => debouncedValidate}
  />
)
```

3. ...tried useCallback:

```js
const debouncedValidate = useCallback(
  debounce((formData, errors) => validate(formData, errors), 300),
  [formData, errors]
);

return (
  <SchemaForm
    validate={(formData, errors) => debouncedValidate}
  />
)
```

1 resulted in a `TypeError: Expected a function`. Lodash is expecting a function without args, like their docs illustrate: `_.debounce(func, [wait=0], [options={}])`. Both 2 & 3 result in an `Uncaught ReferenceError: formData is not defined` error.

Any suggestions as to how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const debouncedValidate =  _.debounce(validate, 300);


return (
  <SchemaForm
    validate={(formData, errors) => debouncedValidate(formData, errors)}
  />
)
```